# Python - why would library version from pip freeze be different than when I actually run it?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

I'm using conda and pip to manage my packages.

In my environment.yml, I have the following

```
  - LOTS OF PACKAGES
  - ...
  - ...
  - pip:
    - pyarrow==0.16.0
```

So pyarrow should be a specific version - 0.16.

I conda activate into that environment. And when I do a pip freeze or pip show, the version agrees. It's supposed to be 0.16

```
(CONDA) $ pip show pyarrow
Name: pyarrow
Version: 0.16.0
Summary: Python library for Apache Arrow
Home-page: https://arrow.apache.org/
Author: None
Author-email: None
License: Apache License, Version 2.0
Location: /home/<USRER>/anaconda3/envs/CONDA/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: numpy, six
```

But when I fire up python, import the library, and try get the version, it's a different version.

```
(CONDA) $ python   
Python 3.6.6 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct  9 2018, 12:34:16) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyarrow
>>> pyarrow.__version__
'0.12.0'
>>> pyarrow.__file__
'/home/<USER>/anaconda3/envs/CONDA/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyarrow/__init__.py'
```

I don't understand how that's possible. I would expect the version to agree, but for some reason python insists that pyarrow is a different version.

Now I suspect my entire conda environment is bad. Shouldn't the version that I get in python agree with pip freeze?

Comment: Does it still happen if you install pyarrow package separately in the env using pip instead of installing through yml file?

Comment: yes i manually did a pip install within my conda environment, and it still has the old version when I actually run python.

Comment: Is pyarrow part of conda list as well in yml file or only in pip list?

Comment: It could be that your `pip` script i snot associated with the Python interpreter you are using. My advice is to always use `python -m pip` to make it explicit. -- https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Comment: @sinoroc It should be, since the `pip show` includes the correct location.

Comment: @user3240688 Do you have to install pyarrow through pip? It's not exactly a solution to the current problem, but it seems to be available as a Conda package ([link](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pyarrow)).

Comment: @AMC, you are correct, my bad. -- Could it be that there are multiple installations of `pyarrow` in the same environment?

Answer (score 0):

pyarrow does some [funny stuff](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/796b050fdec509f74238bb6f3b600a3cea1db57a/python/pyarrow/__init__.py#L37) with the `__version__` variable. It [is generated](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/c90ad63c1b27a2868a7ee6969a31ccda95677a42/python/setup.py#L602) using [setuptools-scm](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools-scm/).

So maybe the conda release you installed is broken for some reason. Maybe try to install it manually by cloning it and installing it with `pip` from the cloned folder without passing through `conda` and see if you get a different result.

I beleive you can do this automagically by running:

```
pip install "git+https://github.com/apache/arrow@apache-arrow-0.16.0#egg=pyarrow&subdirectory=python"
```